# Create Row dynamically in QListWidget

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt

Hi,

I want to create a custome widget. Please help by giving some idea.
My intention is to make a Listwidget which shows some Information and when clicking particulat row it have to show the details coresponding to that row by creating a new area(Row or text edit) immediately below the selected row and pull the other rows below the selected row to down after the created new area.
In attachment when I click row Nancy (consider it as row) her details is coming below the selected row. Please help on this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use is the QTreeView. It is capable of showing rows with text and icons.
You need to define the QStandardItemModel for the table, this will give it column definition.

Below are three relevant functions from a class I wrote for a similar app. Note that I did not need to use any images in my rows so you'll have to figure that part out yourself.

```
def drawPeopleListBox(self):
    header = ["Picture","First Name","Last Name","Title","Address", "City", "Region"]
    self.model = QStandardItemModel(0, len(header), self)
    for i in range(len(header):
        self.model.setHeaderData(i, Qt.Horizontal, self.selectionDict[i+1].upper())

    self.itemList = QTreeView()
    self.itemList.setRootIsDecorated(False)
    self.itemList.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    self.itemList.setSortingEnabled(False)
    self.itemList.setModel(self.model)
    self.itemList.NoEditTriggers=True

    #self.itemList.clicked[QModelIndex].connect(self.onRowClick)
    self.itemList.clicked.connect(self.onRowClick)
    self.itemList.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

    self.itemList.setColumnWidth(0,70)
    self.itemList.setColumnWidth(1,140)
    self.itemList.setColumnWidth(2,70)
    self.itemList.setColumnWidth(3,180)
    self.itemList.setColumnWidth(4,100)
    self.itemList.setColumnWidth(5,100)
    self.itemList.setColumnWidth(6,100)

    self.populateList(self.userDataList)

def populateList(self, userDataList):
        row=[]
        for user in userDataList:
            for attrib in user:
                row.append(QStandardItem(attrib))

            for item in row:
                item.setEditable(False)

            self.model.appendRow(row)

def onRowClick(self, index):
    print index.row()
    '''
    Here you need to resize the clicked row height. Also resise the image.
    Or insert another row that matches your design requirement. 
    self.model.insertRow(rowNumber, listOfQStandardItems)
    '''         
    self.repaint()
```

Comment: can u help me whats self type

Comment: self is a Python class internal element, layman's answer would be, it's Python's equivalent of a protected class element. Now that didn't event make sense to me and I wrote it. I am terrible at explaining things this, sounds like you need to take a crash course in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using a custom delegate to view the rows.  I believe the delegates know if they are selected.  Using this, you would draw the unselected rows normally, and draw more information for the selected rows.  The problem with this is that I don't know if you can resize the widget on selection.  If not, the QTreeView solution should still work.